# Error while connecting to Secure IBM MQ

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq

We've created a java swing project to connect with IBM MQs (secure and non secure). We are using RAD (IBM's V8.5 libraries) and the secure as well as non-secure MQ connections are working fine in this project. But when we created an executable jar file, bundling all the required IBM jar files and SSL certificates and run it, the secure connection doesn't works (non-secure is working fine using executable jar).

```
public MQQueueManager mqConnect(String Qmanager, String hostname, String channel, int port) throws Exception { 
    Hashtable<String, SSLSocketFactory> props = null;
    try {
        props = setSSLKeystore("dev-cert.jks", "Password");

        MQEnvironment.hostname = hostname;
        MQEnvironment.channel = channel;
        MQEnvironment.port = port;

        if(channel.equals(SECURE_CHANNEL)){
             MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA";
        }else{
             MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite="";
        }

        MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);

        MQQueueManager mqQueueManager = (props != null) ? new MQQueueManager(Qmanager, props) : new MQQueueManager(Qmanager);
        return mqQueueManager;
    }catch (MQException mqExp) {
        mqExp.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private Hashtable<String, SSLSocketFactory> setSSLKeystore(String fileName, String password){
    Hashtable<String, SSLSocketFactory> props = new Hashtable<String, SSLSocketFactory>();
    try{
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(fileName), password.toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(ks, password.toCharArray());

        KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ts.load(new FileInputStream(fileName), password.toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ts);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        props.put(MQC.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY_PROPERTY, sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        return props;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();return null;
    }
}
```

I need to know what might be the issue here. This is the exception.

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009
MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect
Closure reason = 2009
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:276)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:301)
       at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:323)
       at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:84)
       at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:173)
       at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:795)
       at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:709)
       at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:664)
       at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:160)
       at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:554)
       at com.mqutility.util.QueueOperations.mqConnect(QueueOperations.java:149)
       at com.mqutility.main.QueueEditor$1.actionPerformed(QueueEditor.java:158)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: com.ibm.mqservices.MQInternalException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009
MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect
Closure reason = 2009
       at com.ibm.mq.MQv6InternalCommunications.checkControlFlags(MQv6InternalCommunications.java:769)
       at com.ibm.mq.MQv6InternalCommunications.establishChannel(MQv6InternalCommunications.java:665)
       at com.ibm.mq.MQv6InternalCommunications.initialize(MQv6InternalCommunications.java:218)
       at com.ibm.mq.MQv6InternalCommunications.<init>(MQv6InternalCommunications.java:111)
       at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSIONClient.MQCONNX(MQSESSIONClient.java:1458)
       at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSIONClient.MQCONN(MQSESSIONClient.java:1369)
       at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:252)
```

Comment: Good question but probably too specific for this place. If you don't receive helpful answers here I would recommend you to try posting at some mq forum at IBM devworks.

Comment: What does the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` show at the time your client app receives this **2009** error?

Comment: @JoshMc is absolutely right, you answer will be found in the queue manager's error log. Without that information we can only guess what your problem might be.

Comment: MQ Manager log says there is a SSLHandshakeException. All the operations related to IBM MQ like connecting with queue manager and then post a message to a queue, list the messages from queue etc. are working with non-secure queue connection in the executable jar. Problem is only while secure SSL connection with the secure queue manager. And this is not happening when I am executing the code from IBM's RAD 8.5 environment that uses IBM's JRE. Do I need to add some libraries related to the secure connection with IBM MQs?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using SSL Cipher Suite (updated the code)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, user9123!  This is a Q&A site and it doesn't work like a forum.  Please update your question (which you can always do with low reputation) with the **full text** of the MQ error log entry resulting from the connection failure.  Please do not put subsequent detail in the comments section as it isn't formattable and will be difficult to read.

Comment: Did you ever find a resulition to this issue?  If not please update the question with the full text of the queue manager's SSLHandshakeException error in the AMQERR01.LOG.